# In Camp Slaughter, does Mario discuss being gay with Ruben?

Tags: movie, horror

In *[Camp Slaughter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camp_Slaughter)*, a Groundhog Day style slasher film involving a group of teens from the 2000s getting stranded in a summer camp trapped in the 1980s, there is a character named Ruben who exhibits a lack of traditional masculinity, and is bullied by some of the other kids in the camp as a result. Mario, one of the contemporary teens, has a heartfelt talk with Ruben on the pier, which I remember seeing stated in at least one review (none of which I can find now) was about Mario's own experience with being gay, trying to console Ruben that it gets better. However, the copy I watched had muddy sound quality and no subtitles (and I'm bad at picking up dialogue in movies when there's background noise). And I haven't had much luck in finding a copy of the shooting script to see if the information is there.

So, does Mario have a conversation with Ruben about being gay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scene is quite brief, and certainly contains a degree of suppressed sexuality. The two boys do hold hands and finally embrace each other. But they do not discuss being gay, and Mario does not console Ruben "that it gets better".

I also could not find a transcript, but this is my version of the scene (all mistakes and omissions are down to me, of course).

---

(Ruben approaches Mario on the dock, and sits down near him, but keeps his gaze averted from him.)

Mario: What?

Ruben: Are you gonna help us?

Mario: I’m not gonna talk to you until you look at me.

(Ruben shyly looks towards Mario)

Ruben: Daniel and Ivan said they asked for you help. And…?

Mario: I don’t know. This is messed up.

Ruben: (smiles) You remind me of my brother.
He’s the only one who took care of me after our parents died.  I miss
him.

(Ruben looks away in pain. Mario holds his hand to comfort him)

Mario: Can I try something?

(Mario moves close to Ruben so they are face to face, sitting cross-legged)

Mario: Relax, and trust me. Put
your hands to your side. Please. And close your eyes.

(Mario reaches one hand towards Ruben’s bare chest. Ruben opens his eyes. They both suddenly have a vision of the body of a murdered girl. Ruben gets to his feet in shock and backs away)

Ruben: Are you OK?

(Mario gets to his feet and walks up to Ruben. They embrace)

Mario: We’re going to
get you out of here. I promise. We’re gonna help you.

(They separate and walk off the dock)

---

Possibly there is another cut of the film which contains extra material, where they discuss being gay. But I doubt it - it sounds more as if the review is just misinterpreting/exaggerating the sexual tension between the boys.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.